# Independance of three random variables

Tags: probability, random-variable

I have a problem in understanding the independence concept. I have this problem.
let us assume that a video frame of size `L` bytes has to be carried over `N` packets. The frame size `L`and the number of packets are both random. now, let the size of the packet be `S`, which is also a random variable since (i guess). I want to compute the expected size of the packet `S`

What is the relationship between the three RVs in term of dependency?

are `N and L` independent?
if yes then

```
S=L/N  ---> E[S]=E[L/N] ---> is this true E[S]=E[L]*E[1/n]   

N is Uniform random variable. RVs are discrete
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. I find it highly unlikely that $L$ and $N$ would be independent of one another. This is likely an erroneous assumption and you should take caution.
2. No, $E[S] \neq E[L] \times E[1/N]$. You would have to find the distribution of $S$ directly from the distribution of $L$ and $N$ unless $L$ is a certain random variable such that $L/N = S$ follows a well-known distribution.

Comment: Regarding  (1), i know that from system operation that N , is chosen randomly and independently within  a range ( for security security purpose ). Does that justify  the independency assumption ?

Comment: You're saying that $N$ is chosen randomly from a set of numbers?  The number of packets $N$ is not affected whatsoever by the video frame size?  I would imagine that if the video frame size $L$ gets larger, $N$ must also get larger. If this is the case, this implies that the two are *not independent.*  However, I know very little about graphics and sending information so my intuition could certainly be off the mark here.